# Ignored if-statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, internet-explorer, if-statement

this is only my second question so please be gentle, I am new to PHP.

I have written a statement that queries a database, then checks a file to see if the relevant is present before creating a div to put the image into. The problem is that the output creates divs for rows that have no images.

```
$query = "SELECT vehicle_make_logo FROM vehicle_makes";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for  ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{       
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   $image = 'images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0];
   if(file_exists($image)){
       echo '<div class="component"><a href=""><img class="icons" src="images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0].'"></a></div>';   
       }    
}
```

I have tried adding an empty else-statement, but that didn't do anything.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IE9 couldn't care less about if()s in PHP. Remember. PHP runs on the server. IE will **NEVER** see the PHP code - it'll just see the HTML that PHP generated.

Comment: You're right, firefox is creating the divs, but displays the result differently. My if statement is just being ignored then?

Comment: php if statements never make it to the browser. They are handled at server side and only the generate HTML goes to the browser. In your case if IE is generating extra divs, the problem is with the displaying CSS or HTML element. 

In order to debug this, try to figure out what those extra divs contain. Could you update your question with that info?

Comment: Please send use the IE browser output. Are you quit sure that you are on the right webpage? Would `print "test"` work before the if, after the if and at least in your for?

Comment: if php root and document root are different then the relative path images/vehicleBrands/ will be different for php and the webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility for what is happening is that your DB table has rows in there which haven an empty field for `verhicle_make_logo`, at which point your if statement is checking if that folder exists, which it obviously does. If you are certain this is not the case ignore the below, if it is then this might be a solution.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT vehicle_make_logo FROM vehicle_makes";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for  ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{       
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   $image = 'images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0];
   if(!empty($row[0]) && file_exists($image)){
       echo '<div class="component"><a href=""><img class="icons" src="images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0].'"></a></div>';   
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had figured out that it was empty cells, the extra validation did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A browser can never overwrite PHP code because it never sees the PHP code. A browser will only render exactly what the PHP code passes to it. In the case where IE creates extra `div` tags, it could be that your HTML is malformed and IE tries to normalise it and creates extra divs in the process to close off some open tags that you may have overlooked.

Try copying the `view-source` code of the page and run it through a HTML validator to see.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever think for a minute that, Whatever kind of **Browser** you are using can actaully influence the way how PHP behaves. Because, it Can not! It may seem that way to you, because sometimes, the **HTML tags/codes**... outputted/echo'ed by your PHP script may be rendered in a different way, according to the browser type you are using, *specially* by IE, because it sucks. Now, to get back to your code, try this

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT vehicle_make_logo FROM vehicle_makes";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rows) > 0) {

    for($j=0; $j < count($rows); ++$j){

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $image = 'images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0];
        if(file_exists($image)){
       echo '<div class="component">
            <a href=""><img class="icons" src="images/vehicleBrands/'.$row[0].'"></a></div>';   
       }    
    }
}else {echo 'No record found';}
```

Comment: This does not work either, due to the crowbared else on line 6

Comment: no it doesn't work, I've figured out the solution now. The database had null entries for some images so the $images variable was still valid even as it contained images/vehicleBrands. By simply changing the column to 'NOT NULL' and adding a file name for an image that doesn't exist, the script returns the right number of divs